# Does tf.trace() only evaluate diagonal elements?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a TensorFlow tensor `t` with shape `(d,d)`, a square matrix. I define the trace tensor `tr = tf.trace(t)`. Now `tr` is evaluated, using `session.run(tr)`: Is TensorFlow smart enough to only evaluate the diagonal elements of `t`, or are all elements of `t` evaluated first, and only then the trace is computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow will compute the matrix first, then run the trace op to extract/sum the diagonal. Potentially this is something that [XLA](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/) could optimize away if no other ops consume the full matrix (not sure if it does or not currently), but TensorFlow itself sees these ops as more or less black boxes.

If there are no consumers of the full matrix, maybe just do computations on a vector representing that diagonal? You could also use [sparse tensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/sparse_ops) to avoid unnecessary computation while keeping track of indices.